# Where can i download some good software design document?

Tags: document

Right now i am designing a software, and i need some good documents for reference.

Where can i download some good system design or UI design documents ?
by the way, i don't want just some document template.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Comment: Ehh... *what* do you want? What kind of software are you designing? What kind of documents do you need? Checklists? Tutorials? About "design" as in UI design or as in application dasign? Please be a lot more specific.

Comment: UI design and database design, sorry to let you confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit hard to answer your question because it's a little vague. Are you talking technical documentation (eg low-level and/or high-level designs, architecture documents, etc) or more business-level documentation (eg requirements, functional specification)?

I would say of these the func spec is the most important, in which case I'd suggest reading:

- [Painless Functional Specifications - Part 1: Why Bother?](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000036.html)
- [Painless Functional Specifications - Part 2: What's a Spec?](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000035.html)
- [The Project Aardvark Spec](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/AardvarkSpec.html)

for a good intro and a good sample func spec (last link).

Comment: it seems that it is really very good !
Thanks!